# Can't stop automatic PostgreSQL start-up on WSL Ubuntu terminal open

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm starting my coding journey and I have set up the Ubuntu terminal(WSL2). I followed this guide my cousin gave me and it included some directions to install PostgreSQL. I thought it would be a good idea to get it ahead of time, but now it's turning into a nightmare. I installed it and followed the directions to make it automatically connect to the server on the Ubuntu terminal start-up. Long story short, it makes the terminal take awhile to start-up, puts my terminal in some weird directory, and I won't even be using it, so we decided to get rid of it. We tried everything and finally decided to just uninstall it. Now on start-up, it's still trying to connect to the server or whatever. I tried running the code to make it automatically start-up again in case it might just toggle it on and off, but now it's attempting to connect three times on open. Please see the directions I used below as well as what my terminal is showing on start-up. Also, when I try commands to end it or whatever, it can't do it because postgresql can't be found (because I uninstalled it). Any thoughts?

**Directions:**
In a few weeks, we'll talk about SQL and Databases and you'll need something called PostgreSQL, an open-source robust and production-ready database.

Let's install it now.

```
sudo apt install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev build-essential
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
sudo -u postgres psql --command "CREATE ROLE `whoami` LOGIN createdb;"
```

You can configure PostgreSQL to autostart, so you don't have to execute sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start each time you open a new terminal:

```
sudo echo "`whoami` ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/postgresql start" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/postgresql
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/postgresql
echo "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start" >> ~/.zshrc
```

**Error Code:**

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/postgresql: command not found
sudo: /etc/init.d/postgresql: command not found
sudo: /etc/init.d/postgresql: command not found
➜  /home
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the offending line from `.zshrc`.

Let me add that the Linux emulation of Windows cannot be used for serious work with a database, as it does not implement the vital system call `fsync` to persist data. Any operating system crash will result in data corruption.

Comment: Could you expand upon "offending line?" Do you mean the `start` prior to .`.zshrc`? Sorry, pretty new to this stuff. Further, what code sequence would you input to undo the automatic start specifically? Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Obviously the `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start` you added to `.zshrc`. Remove it again.